# correlated query to get begin sequence and end sequence in sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this:

```
employee type seq
A        loa  1
A        loa  2
A        rfl  3
A        loa  4
A        rfl  5
A        loa  6
A        loa  7
A        rfl  8
```

now I want a table that gives me for all loa a begin sequence and an end sequence. The begin sequence is just the current sequence of that row. The end sequence is sequence is the first rfl after that sequence. So for my example the result has to be:

```
employee type beginSeq endSeq
A        loa  1        3
A        loa  2        3
A        loa  4        5
A        loa  6        8
A        loa  7        8
```

I thought doing two tables. 
a table `loa`=

```
select * from table where type='loa'
```

and a table `rfl`=

```
    select * from table where type='rfl'
```

Then I just thought I could do this:

```
select loa.* from loa
    left join (select min(seq) from rfl where rfl.seq>=loa.seq)
    on rfl.employee = loa.employee
```

but unfortunately the loa.seq in the subquery is not known at that point.
Someone a suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use *correlated subquery* as :

```
select t.*,
       ( select min(seq) from tab where type = 'rfl' and seq > t.seq )
       as endSeq
  from tab t
 where t.type = 'loa'
 order by t.seq;
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/THGHE1712)

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle, I would use `lead()`:

```
select *
from (select loa.*,
             lead(case when type = 'rfl' then seq end ignore nulls) over (partition by employee order by seq) as end_seq
      from loa
     ) loa
where type = 'loa';
```

The `ignore null`s pulls the next non-`null` value.  The `case` statement is only looking for `'rfl'` values.

You could also express this as:

```
select *
from (select loa.*,
             min(case when type = 'rfl' then seq end) over (partition by employee order by seq rows between current row and unbounded following) as end_seq
      from loa
     ) loa
 where type = 'loa';
```

Comment: How is lead going to select a value from 3rd row instead of 2nd? OP wants 1-3 and 2-3 for 1st and 2nd row.